# Playing mp3s from the middle with or without JavaFX

Tags: java, audio, mp3, playback

Is there a way to play an mp3 in java from a specific starting point without using JavaFX? I tried many libraries but those that I can get to work don't provide functionalities beyond start, pause, stop.

I'm using Eclipse.

Edit: My experience with JavaFX:

- I installed e(fx)clipse.
- I added all their jars to the Build Path.
- I added this to the VM Arguments:

```
    --module-path "C:\my\path\to\External Libraries\javafx-sdk-14\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

- Main's main method launches the javafx application and the start method afterwards, which initializes my Game class with the following code:

```
    package application;

    import java.io.File;
    import javafx.scene.media.Media;
    import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;

    public class Game {

        public Game() {

            String songPath = "C:\\Users\\Dustin\\Meine Dateien\\Musik\\EDM\\1991 - Jungle Cats.mp3";

            Media hit = new Media(new File(songPath).toURI().toString());
            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(hit);
            mediaPlayer.play();
        }

    }
```

- I'm getting the following exceptions:

```
    Exception in Application start method
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager (in unnamed module @0x69d159f0) cannot access class com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.glass.utils to unnamed module @0x69d159f0
        at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.lambda$new$0(NativeMediaManager.java:110)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:554)
        at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.<init>(NativeMediaManager.java:107)
        at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager$NativeMediaManagerInitializer.<clinit>(NativeMediaManager.java:78)
        at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.getDefaultInstance(NativeMediaManager.java:90)
        at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaManager.canPlayProtocol(MediaManager.java:78)
        at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.locator.Locator.<init>(Locator.java:239)
        at javafx.scene.media.Media.<init>(Media.java:393)
        at application.Game.<init>(Game.java:18)
        at application.Main.start(Main.java:21)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
        ... 1 more
    Exception running application application.Main
```

Answer (score 0):

If your library exposes functionality that allows you to read a specific number of frames per buffer, a way to get to a particular time is to read without playback while counting the corresponding number of frames, discarding the data. This sometimes works because audio processing is much faster than the playback of that data. The lag will be proportional to the amount of music you have to skip over to get to the desired spot.

Another strategy is to load the entire file into memory and use the positioning power of a Clip. This can be unworkable if you are dealing with a stream that is many minutes long.

Any particular reason why you don't want to use JavaFX?

Comment: I guess, I'm still kind of new to java. The second method sounds more appropriate to me, but I was actually hoping for a line of code like playClip(File file, float startingPoint). Ashamedly I couldn't get JavaFX to work. Every solved issue was followed by another one. Also it seemed kind of too big to me just to play a file.

Comment: You CAN use Clip by specifying a location. You can either give the frame number or the time in milliseconds. The question is how large is the file, and if you have enough memory to hold it. What are the durations of the files you want to play?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a library that loads an mp3 into a memory array, though. Most of what I've seen is set up for direct playback only. For myself, I tweaked the code of an ogg/vorbis utility. It's not in good shape to recommend to others. It might be best to just use the seek() method of javafx mediaplayer, even if you have to go through some hoops to get javafx to work right. Are you able to handle the basic node structure for GUI elements, or are you getting hung up with those basics?

Comment: Okay, what exactly does it mean to use Clip? Is it a library or ... which methods would I use? Could you add some sample code? Sorry.
I'm going to add my JavaFX problem to the question.

Comment: javax.sound.sampled.Clip is the full name. Part of desktop Java since year 2000.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html The oracle tutorial is here (but not an easy read). https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/playing.html There's plenty of tutorials around on using Clips. But I think you are on a better path by working out the problems you are having with JavaFX/MediaPlayer instead.